# Why index eror occurr in this case and how to fix it

Tags: python, indexing, compiler-errors, discrete-mathematics, index-error

The problem is : Write a function [D,P,F]=formalConvert(S) to extract D and P then convert the statement S from Exercise 1. excluded (f) to formal form F.

Hint: D contains the words between For all/ Exist/ There is at least one and a comma (,); P contains the words after the first word from the comma (,).

And here is my code (python)

```
S = ['For all fishes, they need water to survive',
     'Exist a person, who is left handed',
     'Exist an employee in the company, who is late to work everyday',
     'For all fishes in this pond, they are Koi fish',
     'There is at least one creature in the ocean, it can live on land',
     'Every students in class A did not pass the test'
     ]
A = ['For all ', 'Exist a ','Exist an ', 'There is at least one ']
def formalConvert(S):
    F = 'Formal form : For all x in D, P(x)'
    arr = S.split(', ')
    for a in A:
        if (arr[0].find(a)!=-1):
        
            D = arr[0].replace(a,'')
            P = ' '.join(arr[1].split()[1:])
        else:
            arr1 = s.split(' did not ')
            D = arr1[0].replace('Every ','')
            P = arr1[1].replace('pass','did not pass')
        return [D, P, F]
for s in S:
    print(formalConvert(s))
```

when i run it occure the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\lab3\ex2.py", line 26, in <module>     
    print(formalConvert(s))
  File "d:\lab3\ex2.py", line 20, in formalConvert
    P = arr1[1].replace('pass','did not pass')    
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please clearly format your code and question

Comment: arr1 will contain only 1 element if s does not contain ´ did not’ . So accessing 2nd element is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the else statement, you are splitting by ' did not ', however, most of the strings in your list don't have ' did not ' in them. So the result of  `s.split(' did not ')` does not have two elements, but one. And so if you try to access the "1" element (2nd), your array gets out of range.

Just a friendly note though, try to familiarize yourself with a debugger, it'll be of great help, I assure you.